# How to get a exact decimal precision value without rounding the decimal point value?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have to convert the  double value to CString inorder to display it in the mfc list box. Before displaying it I need to format the decimal points to my required number of digits .

For example here I need to format the double value to 2 digits

```
double a = 4217.088;        
CString str;
str.Format("%.*lf",2,a);
```

Here the assigned value of a is 4217.088. I need the formated str value as 4217.08 but the decimal point value rounds as 4217.09

I also tried with floor method as below but this too gave me the same result.

```
double b;                                   
b = floor(a * 100) / 100;
```

Is there any possibilities to format the double value without rounding the decimal points.

Comment: I get `4217.08` from `floor(a * 100) / 100`. I am using VS2017. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Hello!!. Mine is VS2012.

Comment: That's weird. Try `b = int(4217.088 * 100.) / 100.` Maybe there is a typo.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I got 4217.0799999999999.

Comment: Okay, that's expected. `CString::Format` should round that up to `4217.08`

Comment: @VikranthN please add some more examples of double values and expected output.

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani : This works fine for 5 decimal points.
 My requirement is to set precision value  from 1 to 6.
 So when I applied the same method for 6 decimal places 
 the value of b became -2147.4836479999999 as shown below 
                 

            double a = 4217.08888888;
     double b = int(a * 1000000.) / 1000000.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want simple truncation instead of rounding, you can format with 3 decimals and then trunc the result:

```
double a = 4217.088;   
CString str;
str.Format("%.*lf", 3, a); 
str = str.Left(str.GetLength() - 1);

// str contains now "4217.08"
```

But this works too:

```
double a = 4217.088;
str.Format("%.*lf", 2, std::floor(a * 100) /100);
```

Comment: str = str.Left(str.GetLength() - 1); method helped my requirement . Thankyou so much.

Comment: @VikranthN it's strange that the second method I suggest doesn't work for you though..

Comment: That should probably read `str.Format("%.*lf", 3, a);`, which fails once you pass `0.9999` (or similar values). Scaling by 100 works somewhat more reliable, until scaling exhausts the precision of the mantissa. I'm not absolutely convinced that there aren't other failure modes as well; mixing base-10 math with base-2 representation frequently yields surprising results.

Answer (score 2):

Rounding will not work at all. In your case next digit in 8 which greater than 5 hence it's converting next digit to 9.
To come to your problem, following code should solve the issue:

`double b = std::floor(a * 100.) / 100.;`

Comment: Round the result with two digit. Will get your output.